# Can't find API Access field field on managed package

Tags: managed-package

I'm following the instructions here:
[Manage API and Dynamic Apex Access in Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/editing_client_security_profile.htm)

Specifically:

> - From Setup, enter Installed Packages in the Quick Find box, then select Installed Packages.
> - Click the name of the package you wish to edit.
> - The API Access field displays the current setting, Restricted or Unrestricted, and a link to either Enable Restrictions or Disable Restrictions. If Read, Create, Edit, and Delete access are not selected in the API access setting for objects, users do not have access to those objects from the package components, even if the user has the “Modify All Data” and “View All Data” permissions.

I'm doing the above and do not see a field `API Access`. Am I missing something or is this documentation outdated? Is this now controlled elsewhere?

The documentation also explains this is possible to see on an installed package as well and I don't see it there either.

Comment: Maybe you have to be the installer? From the same document: *API Access is a package setting that controls the dynamic Apex and API access that s-controls and other package components have to standard and custom objects. The setting displays for both the developer and installer on the package detail page.*

Comment: I do not see it in our package development orgs.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm the package developer in my scenario. But I also confirmed in an org where I was the installer (test org) and didn't see it there either.

Comment: @PhilB - I used to be there, I remember it, but it is no longer there and is a doc error IMHO

Comment: @Eric yeah I think so too, my question is where did that functionality go? What happens to packages with restrictions? I guess I'll be logging a case.

Comment: I've reached out to the Salesforce Docs team for clarification. Indications from other channels is that it has been discontinued as a feature.

Comment: Thanks @DanielBallinger! Please post if you hear anything else. I'm curious to know what, if any, are the restrictions now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official word is in from the Salesforce Docs team:

> This attribute was removed from installed packages in Summer '16:
> [Summer '16: API Access settings for installed packages are no longer available](https://t.co/sqR34NO7hJ)

From the linked idea:

> **Description**
> Prior to Summer '16 when users View Installed Package Details the "API Access" attribute was available.
>
> > **Description:** This allowed users to set the type of access that the API and dynamic Apex code that package components have. The default setting is Unrestricted, which means that all package components that access the API have the same access as the user who is logged in. Click Enable Restrictions or Disable Restrictions to change the API and dynamic Apex access permissions for a package.
>
> **Resolution**
> With Summer '16 this attribute has been removed from installed package detail pages.
>
> It has been identified that access settings behind the API Access attribute are only applicable if your organization has a legacy org feature enabled that has now been deprecated. The majority of customers do not have this mentioned feature enabled for their org and it may not be turned on moving forward.
>
> If your organization does not have the deprecated legacy feature enabled then the API Access attribute will no longer be visible upon viewing installed packages because its settings do not apply or actually affect your installed packages. Removal of the attribute will not have an adverse affect or result in any change to the way your installed packages function despite whether or not you may have configured access for them prior to the Summer '16 release.
>
> If your organization happens to have the legacy feature enabled then API access settings are applicable and you will continue to see the attribute for installed packages to properly manage the settings accordingly.